# Нужно ли тире перед "эти" в предложении?

Tags: тире

> Слабоалкогольные, изящно сладкие, эти игристые вина отлично подходят для празднеств.

Нужно ли тире? Вроде как да, но не уверена.

Comment: Как Вы пришли к мысли о тире, на основании чего?

Comment: Изначально фраза была с тире, но меня терзало сомнение

Comment: Вариантов с тире я не встречал.

Comment: Я думаю так: а) Необособленное указательное определение "эти" может стоять только в начале предложения (тогда оно неоднородно по отношению к другим определениям): Эти слабоалкогольные, изящно сладкие игристые вина отлично подходят для празднеств. б) Если определения стоят перед   "эти",   то они обязательно обособляются: Слабоалкогольные, изящно сладкие, эти игристые вина отлично подходят для празднеств. в) Запятой вполне достаточно для выделения определительного ряда, тире будет авторским знаком. (Обычно тире используется для обособлления однородных придаточных, а не для однородных членов).

Comment: @Ксения , Советую оформить этот комментарий как полноценный ответ. Он того заслуживает.

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую ответить

Answer (score 2):

В справочнике под редакцией Лопатина есть материал, где рассматривается обособление определений, стоящих после указательного местоимения http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118 ( § 50)

Там говорится о том, что обычно определения после указательного местоимения не обособляются, но иногда могут обособляться со значением уточнения, например: *этот дорогой для меня человек* или *этот, дорогой для меня, человек*.

(Но в обоих случаях указательное местоимение стоит в начале ряда, при этом оно или неоднородно по отношению ко второму определению, или второе определение поясняет указательное местоимение).

В середине неоднородного ряда (без запятыХ) указательное местоимение находиться не может, поэтому все определения, стоящие перед  ним, обязательно обособляются.

Тогда заданное предложение может иметь следующие варианты:

а) Указательное определение "эти" может стоять только в начале необособленного ряда определений (тогда оно неоднородно по отношению к другим определениям): *Эти /слабоалкогольные, изящно сладкие/ игристые вина отлично подходят для празднеств.*

б) Если определения стоят перед "эти", то они обязательно обособляются: *Слабоалкогольные, изящно сладкие, эти игристые вина отлично подходят для празднеств.*

Какой знак выбрать для обособления (запятая или тире)?

Запятой вполне достаточно для выделения определительного ряда. Тире можно поставить (ошибки не будет), но оно будет скорее авторским знаком. В то же время тире может подчеркнуть дополнительное обстоятельственное значение определений.

(Обычно тире используется для обособления однородных придаточных, а не для однородных членов).

Comment: Благодарю, исчерпывающе

Answer (score 1):

Ответ исправлен.

"Слабоалкогольные, изящно сладкие" — это определения к слову *вина*.
За ними стоят другие определения ("эти игристые"). Согласен с Niemand, что здесь подходит п.6 (определения имеют добавочное обстоятельственное значение) ([Обособленное определение](https://lampa.io/p/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-00000000b643c559a88a5950364e4e75))

Пример из Нацкорпуса:

> Строгая, благородная, эта музыка требует от исполнителя его собственной внутренней содержательности, душевной зрелости, она как бы поднимает вас до своего уровня. [И. К. Архипова. Музыка жизни (1996)]

Comment: *5. Если определение, стоящее до или после определяемого слова, оторвано от определяемого слова другими членами предложения* -- Нет, здесь применяется не это правило. **6.      Обособляются согласованные распространенные или одиночные определения, стоящие непосредственно перед определяемым существительным, если они имеют добавочное обстоятельственное значение (причинное, условное, уступительное, временное), например: Широкая, свободная, аллея вдаль влечёт (Брюсов); Взъерошенный, немытый, Нежданов имел вид дикий и странный (Тургенев); Сконфуженный, Миронов поклонился в спину ему (Горький).**

Comment: @Niemand Я исправил ответ. Спасибо!